# trying to build a application using flask but getting 404 page not found error when i submit the button

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a application using flask to submit the login button, but I am getting an error 404 page not found

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/success/<name>")

def success(name):
    return 'welcome %s' % name

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user=request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success',name=user))
    else:
        user=request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for("success",name=user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is the login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{url_for('predict')}}" method="POST">
    <p>Enter Name:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nm"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="predict"/> 
    </p>
    </form>
</body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Did you define the succes page somewhere? I don't see it here.

Comment: As a side point, @indu, best practice is to use [template strings](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) for user inputs

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like you’re trying to POST the form data to a `/predict` endpoint that doesn’t exist. Try changing that to `/login`.
2. You need some html to load the success page too. You should be using the `render_template()` function for that html and passing `name` as a variable to that function. Then using the `{{name}}` templating pattern in that html to display the result.